# What is the priority with nested case, for and if loop?

Tags: c, switch-statement, break, subroutine

I have a program similar to this:

```
switch(x)
{ case 1:

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   if ((i==3) || (i==4) || (i==5) || (i==6) || (i==7))
   {
      if (foobar[i])
         break;    // i am talking about this break
   }
}
...further program
break;   /not this break
```

if `foobar[i]` is true, would the program break out of the `case` label or the `for` loop?

Comment: Why not test it for yourself?

Comment: Have you built a test case and are confused about the result? This is straight forward enough to try on your own.

Comment: What language has the multiple breaks option?  is it scheme?

Comment: @AntP, C++ isn't language where you can just test code.

Comment: The compiler turns your program into a parse tree. Everything in the parse tree has a parent, except the root. The break statement must have a parent loop somewhere up the tree. In your code parent of break is for-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for` loop.

Please see: [`break` Statement (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx):

> The break statement **ends execution of the nearest enclosing loop or
>   conditional statement in which it appears**. Control passes to the
>   statement that follows the ended statement, if any.

Answer (score 12):

The `break` follows a LIFO type nature, that is, the last `break` will come out of the first control structure. So, the `break` that you chose would break out of the for-loop, not the `case`.

Answer (score 2):

break will only break out of the for loop. If you have nested statements, it will only break out one level

Answer (score 1):

Is the for loop. The break will bubble up until find the first for, while or a switch.
So you can just write your program like this:

```
switch(x){
    case 1:
        int loopBreaked = 0; //If you want to know if the loop has breaked
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (i <= 7 && i >= 3 && foorbar[i]) {
                loopBreaked = 1;
                break; //breaks the loop
            }
        }
        break; //breaks the switch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How about:**

```
for(i=3; i<=7 && !foobar[i]; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, `break` will break out of the innermost statement of the type `for` `do` `while`, or `switch`. There is no need to break out of an `if` statement, since simply ending the code block will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` will break the `for` loop. And the `break` you using later, break the `switch`. You can consider this code sample:

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
   {
     //statements
      break;
    }
//statements
break;
}
```

the `break` inside the inner loop break the inner loop and the following `break` statement will break the outer loop. In your code sample, the `break` you noticed is inside the `for` loop. So, the `for` loop will break.